# How to authenticate multiple account using tweepy and Twitter API v2

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I've been trying to write a script which posts a tweet to all authorized user accounts. I have tried using PIN-based authentication for this. The problem is that no matter how many accounts i authorize, the create_tweet function only posts to one account that is my developer account. What am i doing wrong, how can i authenticate multiple accounts?

```
import tweepy
import config

#Initialize client object and user handler with necessary keys
client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=config.API_KEY,
    consumer_secret=config.API_SECRET,
    access_token=config.ACCESS_TOKEN,
    access_token_secret=config.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
)
oauth1_user_handler = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
    config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET,
    callback="oob"
)

#get the authorization url in which you can authorize an account
print(oauth1_user_handler.get_authorization_url())
#input the pin the account gets after authorizing
verifier = input('PIN: ')
#get the access tokens even though i don't know how to use them
access_token, access_token_secret = oauth1_user_handler.get_access_token(
    verifier=verifier
)
#create a tweet to the account that is authenticated
client.create_tweet(text='hello', user_auth=True)
```

I haven't tried OAuth2 authentication yet, maybe that's the solution?

Comment: Where is the part of the code that posts to the second account?

Comment: I don’t know how to post to the second account, where can i even enter the access token of the second account to post to it?

Comment: In the same way you enter the access token of the first account?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, i was so lost lol, i thought there could be only one Client object.